# Can't figure out how to find how many books were loaned by each library branch

Tags: sql, oracle

The relation between the two tables is,

```
CREATE TABLE library_branch 
(
    branchID NUMBER, 
    branchName varchar(20), 
    address varchar(20), 
    PRIMARY KEY(branchID)
)

CREATE TABLE book_loan 
(
    bookID varchar(20), 
    branchID NUMBER, 
    cardNo NUMBER, 
    dateOut DATE, 
    dueDate DATE, 
    PRIMARY KEY(bookID, branchID, cardNo), 
    FOREIGN KEY(branchID) REFERENCES library_branch(branchID)
)
```

The question is: for each library branch, retrieve the branch name and the total number of books loaned out from that branch

I have written a query to find out which library branch loaned which books but can't figure out how to find how many books were loaned by each library branch.

Any help to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: On a side note: book_loan's primary key is a little strange. It seems to allow you to borrow each book only once in your life from a branch (once per cardno).

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(bookId), branchName from library_branch
left outer join book_loan on book_loan.branchId = library_branch.branchId
group by branchName
```

This selects **all** rows from library_branch, then joins those rows with any matching rows from book_loan.
It then counts any rows with a non-null bookId and sums those counts by branch.

Note that count(*) would be incorrect, as it would return at least 1 for each branch even if no books were loaned.

Comment: this would return the total number of loans for each branch, not the total number of books loaned: if a book is loaned twice it would be counted twice

Comment: @re_arg: The question is a bit ambiguous here. If a branch loans 10 books a day, we could say they loan 300 books a month, no matter if they loan the same books again and again. So you just interprete the question differently from Individualist. My interpretation is still different, because when I am asked how many books has the branch loaned, I will answer how many are currently loaned.

Comment: @Individualist: It is `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`. So the keyword `LEFT` is needed, only the keyword `OUTER` is optional. And although bookid and branchname only occur in one of the tables, it is still recommended to qualify all columns with their table names, when working with more than one table. Table aliases help with readability.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner added "LEFT" to my original answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Books per branch" translates to `GROUP BY branchid` in SQL. Well, and "how many" is `COUNT(*)`. You get that information from the book_loan table. To find out how many books are loaned at the moment, look at the dates. The loans in question will have a dateOut of today or in the past and a dueDate in the future.

In Oracle you get the current day with `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`.

At last you want information about the branch itself. So select that information from the branch table, then join the subquery that gets you the count per branch. Use an outer join so as to include the branches that have not currently loaned any books.

```
select b.branchid, b.branchname, coalesce(l.loaned, 0) as currently_loaned
from library_branch b
left outer join
(
  select branchid, count(*) as loaned
  from book_loan
  where dateout <= trunc(sysdate)
  and duedate > trunc(sysdate)
  group by branchid
) l on l.branchid = b.branchid
order by b.branchid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your query to know which books have been loaned from which branch, the next step is to **group by** the branch and **count** the amount of books loaned. This can be achieved with:

```sql
SELECT branchName, COUNT(DISTINCT bookId) as booksLoaned
FROM library_branch lb INNER JOIN book_loan bl ON lb.branchId = bl.branchId
GROUP BY branchName
```

I used `DISTINCT` because you mentioned you need the number of books loaned not the number of loans, so with that each `bookId` is only counted once. If you need the total number of loans you can just use `COUNT` directly instead.

**EDIT:**

```sql
SELECT branchName, COUNT(DISTINCT bookId) as booksLoaned
FROM library_branch lb LEFT OUTER JOIN book_loan bl ON lb.branchId = bl.branchId
GROUP BY branchName
```

change the `inner join` to a `left outer join` if you want to also return branches that have not loaned any books.

Comment: Hi, it is `COUNT(DISTINCT bookId)`, not `COUNTDISTINCT(bookId)`. And although bookid and branchname only occur in one of the tables, it is still recommended to qualify all columns with their table names, when working with more than one table.

Comment: thanks, I've fixed the `DISTINCT` on the answer. I had seen that Oracle has a `COUNTDISTINCT` function but its only for Endeca EQL